# Mapping and Reducing an Array within an Array of Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, reduce

I'd appreciate any advice on the below. I need to extract the keywords from the array within an array of objects below, and reduce them to show all keywords without repetition.

My *data* JSON object is below:

```
[
  {
    "word":"Cat",
    "answer":"A type of feline",
    "keywords": ["pet", "mouse-catcher"]
  },
  {
    "word":"Dog",
    "answer":"A type of canine",
    "keywords": ["pet", "cat-catcher"]
  },
]
```

My JS code is below:

```
let keywordList = data.map(entry => {

  let list = [...entry.keywords];
    return (
      list.reduce(( finalArray, current ) => finalArray.concat(current),[])
  );
});
```

Within my React component, I iterate over the array using map again:

```
<p>
  keywords: {keywordList.map((word, index) => {
    return (
      <span key={word+index}>
        <a onClick={this.searchKeyword} href="#" id={word}>{word}</a>
        <span> | </span>
      </span>
    );

  })}
</p>
```

Unfortunately, my reduce function doesn't seem to be working, I'm getting an array of arrays. Any advice would be great.

Comment: Yes, you're clearly creating an array of arrays. Why don't you show us what the data should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `map`, a `reduce` with a `filter`:

```
var list = data.reduce((p, c) => {
  return p.concat(c.keywords.filter(el => !p.includes(el)));
}, []);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rL1esft3/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
let data = [{
    "word": "Cat",
    "answer": "A type of feline",
    "keywords": ["pet", "mouse-catcher"]
  }, {
    "word": "Dog",
    "answer": "A type of canine",
    "keywords": ["pet", "cat-catcher"]
  }
]

let keywords = [...new Set(data.reduce((a, e) => a.concat(e.keywords), []))]
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/912nn6tL/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need, although all the answers here are great, and work perfectly! I need to practice using the reduce function more, thank you!

Comment: How do I mark it as answered? I upvoted both correct answered, but my vote is not registered as I don't have enough 'reputation, but I am unaware of how to mark it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Done, thanks, I never noticed the tick mark there before, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [
  {
    "word":"Cat",
    "answer":"A type of feline",
    "keywords": ["pet", "mouse-catcher"]
  },
  {
    "word":"Dog",
    "answer":"A type of canine",
    "keywords": ["pet", "cat-catcher"]
  },
]

const keywords = [ ...arr.reduce((keywords,obj)=> [...keywords, ...obj.keywords ], [] )
                  .reduce((set,keyword)=> set.add(keyword), new Set() ) ]
```

The first reduce merges all keywords with repetition by concatenation and the second reduce converts the array into a Set removing all duplication. Finally, I wrap it with the resulting set with
[ ...Set ] to convert it into an array.

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/zoruwij/edit?js,console)

Comment: Thanks, all the answers here are great, and much appreciated – although my upvote is not registered as I don't have enough 'reputation'. Thanks very much to all!